# Как получить информацию о файле GIF

Tags: c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить и вывести информацию без использования специальных классов каких-либо библиотек обработки формата GIF? А именно, следующую информацию: размер изображения, глубина цвета, количество страниц, плотность, размер палитры, тип сжатия. Язык - С++.

Answer (score 3):

На `OC Windows` можно воспользоваться методами `GDI+`, которые поддерживается версиями, начиная с `Windows XP` *(нативно)* и с `Windows NT` *(руками*).

Соответственно, вам необходимо воспользоваться классов [**Image**,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534462(v=VS.85).aspx) из которого как раз можно извлечь всю интересующую вас информацию.

Еще более удобный вариант *(правда он не подходим вам по требованию "без специальных классов", но требование, честно говоря, странное)* - использование шаблонной библиотеки [**CImg.**](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Но всё-таки без классов это можно как-нибудь сделать

Comment: Можно! А нужно ли? Если да, то берите спецификацию формата gif и считывайте файл, а затем анализируйте считанное. При этом удобно воспользоаться концепцией структур. Это позволяет поля и атрибуты файла считывать одним махом, а не байт за байтом. К тому же форматы вроде gif предполагают наличие повторяющихся массивов данных в файле. Их тоже может быть удобно реализовать через структуры. А классы, по простому, - это структуры и функции работы с ними, но в одном флаконе. Это тоже удобно, но никто так делать не заставляет.

Comment: А как считать файл?

Comment: @Buba Моя интуиция подсказывает мне, что, если вы задаете вопросы *"Как считать файл?"*, то стоит все-таки пользоваться сторонними библиотеками.

Comment: Но мне надо без библиотек

Comment: А стандартные fopen() и fread() чем не устраивают?

Answer (score 1):

Ничего сложного. [Этого](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/algorithm/127083/) должно хватить.

Comment: А ты бы не мог скинуть пример программы

Comment: ещё http://giflib.sourceforge.net/whatsinagif/bits_and_bytes.html хорошая ссылка